# Load csv with omnivore in Mapbox from from local file

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

Using the example [here](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/markers-from-csv/) I'm trying to add markers to a map using files and code from my local directory. In the directory I have airports.csv & index.html. I can't get the map to show the markers. This is the line of code i use to load the csv all other code is as the original example and copied into the index.html file ;

`omnivore.csv('airports.csv'/assets/data/airports.csv').addTo(map);`

I've tried copying in the full file path as well but this makes no difference to the outcome. I've also tried calling a url for the same file stored [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vT2IV8wf2DFKEYfTRmIcXUJP4eL6ESJGB6STfJiM8JMGxDXWm1Eh0lyVbPD60Dq9gYT66-SAD1XlyvQ/pub?gid=621526705&single=true&output=csv). I'm new to html / javascript. Any help gratefully appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both your `index.html` file and your `airports.csv` file are located in the very same folder, then you should be able to load the CSV file using directly:

```
omnivore.csv('airports.csv').addTo(map);
```

Note that if the CSV file is very big, you will have to wait for a few seconds (up to minutes, depending on your bandwidth…) for the browser to fetch the file from the server.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, the file is 140kb. It's stored locally so the only thing the browser is fetching remotely are the code libraries that transfrom the csv into GeoJson. Does this involve sending the data across? Now i know that part of the code is correct i'll see if something else is causing the problem

Comment: "Does this involve sending the data across?" no, but you can inspect the library code to check what it does exactly.